# How do I make SVG components?

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to make a set of self contained SVG components which include CSS and Javascript, that can be added to a web page via templating. The idea is to be able to add self contained components without changing the base web page. A component could be something like like:

```html
<div id="component-1" ...>
    <svg>
        <css>
            .. css for styling component
        </css>

        <line ...>
        <text ....>
          ... component svg

        <script>
            .... functions that manipulate the component
        </script>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The same component may be added multiple times. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: The framework for doing that is the [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks!

Comment: There is no `<css>` tag, use `<style>`